# configuring bind to serve a default IP for DNS queries

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, bind

I'm setting up a meeting and I'd like to have the computers here (which are for accessing the meeting website only) blocked from accessing the public Internet.

I'd like to set up bind to return the same IP for *ALL* DNS queries - no passing upstream, no "not found". Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this I believe you would create a master zone named "." in your named.conf (comment out the default "." zone with the hints information).  Then, create a zone file which contains a series of wildcard records for the IP that you want to have everyone directed to.

If other people will be connecting their own computers to this network for the meeting, then keep in mind that some people will use their own DNS settings (OpenDNS, Google Public DNS, etc.) instead of the DNS server issued by DHCP, so unless you're blocking DNS at the firewall there is still a way around it.  An HTTP proxy server at your routing point might be a better solution if that is the case.

Comment: Thanks! People with their own computers are welcome to surf, we just want to ensure the public terminals aren't taken up with folks checking webmail. This'll work nicely. :-)

Comment: In that case you might also consider running the web browser with a kiosk plug-in which limits what they can do with the computer.  Webconverger.org has a free Debian LiveCD you can customize to go to a specific URL and disable the address bar, etc.  This gets people to the web site and also locks the system down so they can't use the computer for anything else.