# Bind DNS Server default IP when no record

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

I have a Bind DNS server and want to return a specific ip if no record can be found for a request. How can i achive this?

Comment: Do you want to do this for subdomains of a single domain, or every domain you ever get asked about? If the latter, how do you resolve domains which your instance of Bind does not control?

Comment: I want to do this for every domain. The bind Server resolves "normal" domains with the root servers and has a internal list too.

Answer (score 0):

See if this answer helps you: [configuring bind to serve a default IP for DNS queries](https://serverfault.com/questions/132023/configuring-bind-to-serve-a-default-ip-for-dns-queries).

Hope it helps you.

Seems to me that this question belongs to https://serverfault.com/ site ;) Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This feature has apparently been added in BIND 9.9 - otherwise known as NXDOMAIN rewriting.